# Generating a json for a icon cheatsheet

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

I'm trying to generate a json file containing the filenames of all the files in a certain directory. I need this to create a cheatsheet for icons.

Currently I'm trying to run a script locally via terminal, to generate the json. That json will be the input for a react component that will display icons. That component works, the create json script doesn't.

Code for generating the json

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * Create JSON file
 */
const CreateJson = () => {
  const files = [];
  const dir = '../icons';

  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(filename => {
    const name = path.parse(filename);
    const filepath = path.resolve(dir, filename);
    const stat = fs.statSync(filepath);
    const isFile = stat.isFile();

    if (isFile) files.push({ name });
  });

  const data = JSON.stringify(files, null, 2);
  fs.writeFileSync('../Icons.json', data);
};

module.exports = CreateJson;
```

I run it in terminal using
"create:json": "NODE_ENV=build node ./scripts/CreateJson.js"

I expect a json file to be created/overridden. But terminal returns:

$ NODE_ENV=build node ./scripts/CreateJson.js
✨  Done in 0.16s.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a function `CreateJson` and exporting it, but you are actually never calling it.

You can get rid of the `module.exports` and replace it with `CreateJson()`.

When you'll execute the file with node, it will see the function declaration, and a call to it, whereas with your current code there is no call.